# 'mod_ty': Undeclared Identifier

Tags: python, visual-c++, python-2.7, compiler-errors

While compiling an VC++2008 Project with python-2.7.6 as reference i get the following error

> Python27/symtable.h(55): error C2065: 'mod_ty': Undeclared Identifier

Line 55/56 includes:

```
PyAPI_FUNC(struct symtable *) PySymtable_Build(mod_ty, const char *,
                                          PyFutureFeatures *);
```

I'm includeing the follwing:

```
#include "Python27/node.h"
#include "Python27/grammar.h"
#include "Python27/token.h"
#include "Python27/parsetok.h"
#include "Python27/errcode.h"
#include "Python27/compile.h"
#include "Python27/symtable.h"
#include "Python27/eval.h"
#include "Python27/marshal.h"
```

My Build env is: Win7 x32, VC++08 compiler

**But, how to fix this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

mod_ty is present inside Python-ast.h (on python 2.7) which you have not included.